# menu_main.xml preview does not synchronize ( Android Studio 1.1.0 )

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

menu_main.xml preview does not synchronize.
(Android Studio 1.1.0, and I have java 8.)

I synchronized the project, cleared it, and refreshed the preview.. but I still can't see any changes on the preview.

Other layouts previews are working fine, the problem is only with menu_main.xml preview.


**UPDATE** 
Everything is fine now on *Android Studio 1.2.0*

Comment: Maybe the xml has some errors. Can you post the file please?

Comment: @ByteHamster [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_x5fxCwKGcwQ0tVbTFLNkR6REU/view)

Answer (score 0):

Copy the code from main_activity.xml. Clear main_activity.XML. Create a main_activity.xml Insert the code into it.

Comment: I don't have "wrapper" folder, I only have "caches" and "daemon" folders.

Comment: And how to solve this error? I tried to open android studio as administrator, and then synchronized the project.. but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I ran into this issue .. assuming that And. Studio does auto save and that propagates to the preview window. I had to actually click Ctrl-Save for the layout resource I updated, and then sometimes had to refresh the preview window.

But if I didn't explicitly save, the changes would not propogate

Comment: Unfortunately nothing changes.. :(

Comment: Hmm .. maybe if it's just for that one file, there is something corrupt in the project.  Have you tried reconstructing the files in a new project .. say starting with menu_main.xml, to see if it refreshes in a more "isolated" state ? .. and determine if it's the file itself , or something in the project.  Because yes, I agree .. sounds odd if all files refresh except one.  I would figure/guess either all refresh, or none do ..

Comment: Maybe the xml has an issue then ?  In that case - as ByteHamster mentions, it would help if we can see the full xml you are describing

Comment: I'm not sure about that XML I saw there.  I would suggest you update your original post with a code block that has that xml .. and then others might be able to see something there.  In general I find it helps to dial the xml  (or any code that's giving grief) , back to absolutely minimal state and see if it works there.  And then I would do small things like even try a different file name, and make sure the same code is breaking.  I know Android APIs can be fickle sometimes it seems.  Sorry I couldn't get you a better answer on this particular issue for the moment